# Importance of $\alpha/\pi$

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, physical-constants, scattering-cross-section

What is the physical meaning or importance of $\alpha / \pi$ ($\alpha$ being the fine-structure constant)? I have seen that it is the parameter in the expansion of the g-factor but I can not reach to have more insight on it.

Also I have been told that the cross section ratio
$$\frac{\sigma(A+B\gamma)}{\sigma(A+B)}$$
should be of the order of $\alpha / \pi$ ($\gamma$ being the photon and $A$ and $B$ any initial and final state, respectively) but I don't see why or I don't know how to look for further references of such a specific thing.

Comment: Do you know how scattering amplitudes can be expressed as a power series in the coupling constant in question?

Comment: No, I don't know why precisely α/π

Comment: Can you please add the reference where you saw this explicit factor?

Comment: The $\alpha$ is what is important as the perturbative expansion parameter. It is not always divided by a $\pi$. For example, the energy level of hydrogen according to the Dirac equation don’t have this $\pi$ in their expansion.

Comment: A professor of mine told me the thing of the g-factor and this production cross section ratio and my question arises due to this conversation and not because I saw it somewhere.

Comment: The $\pi$ isn’t that important. It happens in some expansions and not in others. Don’t worry about understanding when it happens and when it doesn’t. Concentrate on learning how to do the calculations.

Comment: @María α/π comes naturally in the calculation. $\pi$ comes from doing dimensional regularization. $\alpha$ is just coupling expansion. The same thing happens in the cross-section ratio. See Peskin book (chapter 6)-Vertex correction and Infrared divergences part. You can find these factors essentially. The significance of $\pi$ in the denominator is just coincidence by doing Dimensional regularization integral(or any other regularization).

Comment: This might not be helpful because it is just speculation or wrong Paper by Atiyah"THE FINE STRUCTURE CONSTANT". He tries to derive Fine structure constant like an expansion similar to $\pi$.

Comment: @Hare That seems more like an answer than like a comment.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!